# How to find a cell in a table based on two parameters (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table where I need to find a final score based on time used (Column A and B)  and points scored(row 2). e.g. If the person used 43 seconds and scored 11 points, the final score would be 10.

My first thought was too loop through the time to get the row number like this:

```
Do Until (.Range("A" & i).Value <= time) And _
(.Range("B" & i).Value >= time)
    i = i + 1
Loop
cellN = i
```

And then loop through the points to get the column letter and then add them together with something like this:

```
finalScore = .Range(cellL & cellN).Value
```

But how do I loop through the columns? And is there an easier way of storing the final score in a variable?

[image]

Comment: You don't need to worry about column letters if you use `Cells(rowNum, colNum)` instead of `Range()`

Comment: I cannot understand too much from your question... What input do you have?  A time from columns A:B? Being Low and High, an average should be considered? Two values would be returned (based on the score points of the second row and the points on the row where the time has been found)? In order to be helped you must make us understand what you want accomplishing. What input you have and how the output will be calculated...

Comment: @FaneDuru I'm sorry if my question was unclear. I have two inputs: time and points. By using those two I need to find the find the corresponding score. If the time used (in seconds) is between the values in column A and B, the final score would be on that row. E.G. If the time is 43 I know that the final score is on row 17 (between 42-44). And if the input points was 3, the final score would be 4.

Comment: Then, try my answer code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next function, please:

```
Function FinalScore(lTime As Long, points As Long) As Long
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
  Dim colP As Long, i As Long
  
    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your specific worksheet
    lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = sh.cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If lTime >= sh.Range("A" & i).Value And _
                 lTime <= sh.Range("B" & i).Value Then
            colP = WorksheetFunction.Match(points, sh.Rows(2), 0)
            FinalScore = sh.cells(i, colP).Value: Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

It can be called/checked in this way:

```
Sub testFinalScore()
   MsgBox FinalScore(43, 11)
End Sub
```

This is the basic. It must be improved with some error handling part. To warn in case of not using `Long` variables as parameters, if they exceed the existing range limits etc...

Comment: This works great when the points are positive. But when the points are negative I get the error "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class". Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @user8837495: It shouldn't. What does it return for `MsgBox FinalScore(7, -3)`. I tested and no error appears... Maybe the second row is formatted as text. In such a case try, please: `MsgBox FinalScore(7, "-3")`. Does it work?

Comment: I still get the same error. It seems to happen on row `colP = WorksheetFunction.Match(points, sh.Rows(2), 0)`

Comment: @user8837495:  Strange... Try formatting the second row as Text and then run `FinalScore(7, "-3")`.

Comment: Yet again you save the day. For some reason the negative values in the second row was formatted as Text. When I formatted it to numbers everything worked out!

Comment: @user8837495: Glad I could help!. `Match` function works for both cases, but `Lookup_value` value must be formatted as `Lookup_array`. Or vice versa... :)